# Can tab bar focus be hide when tab bar is not in focus in tvOS 13?

Tags: swift, focus, tvos, tabbar

Can tab bar focus be hide when tab bar is not in focus in tvOS 13

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can tab bar be hide when focus goes from tab bar to collection view in tvOS 13? And i don't have code for this.